# List manipulation in CLIPS (expert system)

Tags: clips

I just want a function to print on item per line.
I am trying:

```
(deffunction myprint (?first $?rest)
(if (neq ?rest nil) then
    (printout t ?first crlf)
    (myprint ?rest)))
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the length function to determine if a list is empty (a return value of 0). Comparing a list to the symbol nil will always fail.

You want to print ?first even if ?rest is empty. Otherwise the last element will never be printed.

It is not necessary to use recursion.

```
CLIPS> 
(deffunction myprint ($?rest)
   (foreach ?r $?rest
      (printout t ?r crlf)))
CLIPS> (myprint a b c)
a
b
c
CLIPS> (myprint (create$ a b) (create$ c d))
a
b
c
d
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution not only solved my problem but also taught how to use create$. It is kind of hidden in the documentation.